# Chrome DevTools / Firebug: how to persist breakpoints with cache busting

Tags: firebug, browser-cache, google-chrome-devtools

I've got very simple cache busting in force for development on my JavaScript files so that every time I make a change, the browser has the most up to date version. Basically:

```
cache_buster = ''
if is_development:
   cache_buster = '-' + file_modified_timestamp_of('/dev/myproject/js/myfile.js')
out += '<script src="/js/myfile' + cache_buster + '.js" />'
```

(The dev server maps requests to `/js/myfile-[0-9]+.js` to `/js/myfile.js` on disk)

My problem is that every time I set a breakpoint in the javascript file, the breakpoint is lost when the source file changes.

Is there any way of remembering or persisting breakpoints in either Chrome DevTools or Firebug which can survive this sort of file name change?

Or is there a superior technique which accomplishes these 2 opposing goals (cache busting & breakpoint persisting)?

Comment: This might not work for you situation, but you could put 'debugger' statements in your code instead of "manually" setting them in the Sources panel.

https://devsite.googleplex.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#debugger